# Uploading image to ServiceNow in C# via REST API

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to upload image to `ServiceNow` incident using SNow `API` provided in this link:
https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/orlando/rest/c_AttachmentAPI#r_AttachmentAPI-POSTmultipart

I've written below `C#` code to post the image:

```
    string url = "https://mycompany.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/upload/"
        , userName = "MyUser", passwd = "MyPassword";

    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passwd),
    };

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
    {

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        multipartContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("incident"), "table_name");
        multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("f264fd3a1bghghgjjhg8f7b4bcbb6"), "table_sys_id"); // id of my incident
        multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\MyImage.jpeg")), "uploadFile", "MyImage.jpeg");

        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), multipartContent).Result;
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
```

However, I keep getting:

> Requested URI does not represent any resource

What could be the problem and how to adjust the code accordingly?

Comment: Just remove the trailing "/" from your url - string url = "https://mycompany.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/upload"

Comment: @Sergey did that, now a new message comes in: `Failed to create the attachment. File part might be missing in the request` :(

Comment: You have to post a new message.

Comment: you mean to use another incident ?

Comment: made some changes to the code adding double qoutes around the keys in the headers. I will post the new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the "/" at the end of the `url`, and also adding double qoutes around the keys in the headers as I read from this post:

https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=328614ffdb00eb808e7c2926ca9619ad&view_source=searchResult

The final working code is:

```
string url = "https://mycompany.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/upload"
    , userName = "MyUser", passwd = "MyPassword";

var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passwd),
};

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
{

    // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var fileStream = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\Image.jpeg"));
            fileStream.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            fileStream.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            fileStream.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            fileStream.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"form-data;name=\"uploadFile\"; filename=\"{"Image.jpeg"}\"");

            var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("incident"), "\"table_name\"");
            multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("f264fd3a1bghghgjjhg8f7b4bcbb6"), "\"table_sys_id\"");
            multipartContent.Add(fileStream, "uploadFile");

    var response = httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), multipartContent).Result;
    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```